# Convert a list into a string

Tags: r

I would like to convert value stored as a `list` into a single string.

For example:

```
l <- list(1,2,3,4)
```

would give:

```
"1234"
```

and not as using the output of `unlist()`:

```
unlist(l)
#[1] "1" "2" "3" "4"
```

Comment: Try `paste(l, collapse='')`

Comment: Maybe safer of what @akrun suggested is `paste(unlist(l), collapse='')`, that works even if the length of each element of `l` is greater than one.

Answer (score 37):

```
 paste( unlist(l), collapse='')
```